# How to identify the 'URL' property within the ADF for SAP ECC connector (Linked Service)

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are trying to setup Linked Service for the SAP ECC connection within the Azure Data Factory. One of the required properties is "URL" which we are not sure how to format it (please see the attached screenshot). Is this an SAP server name? We need to connect multiple tables/views (approx. 150 of them). Do we need to use separate URL for each table/view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an SAP server name?

At the place of URL, **we need to enter the URL of the `SAP ECC OData service.`**

**You must expose the SAP ECC entities via OData services through SAP Gateway in order to utilize this connector or linked service for SAP ECC.**

For exposing SAP ECC data through OData services Building a service is a fairly common use case for SAP NetWeaver Gateway. With the TCODE SICF you to instantly activate the OData service. The objects that must be exposed can also be configured.

see this [step-by-step guidance](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/26/step-by-step-guide-to-build-an-odata-service-based-on-rfcs-part-1/) to build an OData Service blog by **Volker Drees**.

Example (`SAP ECC OData URL`):

```
http://eccsvrname:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/zgw100_dd02l_so_srv/
```

**Reference:**  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-ecc?tabs=data-factory